# Who's that in the wall in Reachcliff Cave

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was doing the daedric quest *The Taste of Death*, where one task is to clear *Reachcliff Cave* from *Draugr*.

[image: Global map showing Reachcliff Cave]

When I'm sneaking through dungeons, the *Aura Whisper* "shout" shows me where other living things *(mostly enemies)* wait for me.

So I explored and cleared said dungeon for my friend *Eola*, that she could get back in to eat some humans. But ... **who's that** ... there's still something **in/behind that wall?** What is that? Can I eat it?

[image: Image of something in that wall ...]
[image: Local map of something]

Comment: +1 for creepiness.  Random person hanging out in the wall = terrifying

Comment: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Mephala#Mephala

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the `tcl` (toggle clipping) console command, you can fly into a hidden room with a hidden NPC.

The "Voice of Namira" is a standard-looking naked elf who won't respond to talking. She is related to the Daedric quest [The Taste of Death](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Taste_of_Death).

Comment: Good find! I'll have to try this next time I see some.

Comment: So it looks like they need a dummy NPC to attribute to the Daedra herself. Good find.

Comment: I wonder if you can kill and eat the "voice of Namira" :P

Comment: I mean .. if she is just there to speak, she wouln't need like her arm or so.

Answer (score 4):

This is almost pure speculation, but I suspect it is a quest-related "phantom" life sign.

I have seen this in a number of places (as a sneaky sort, Aura Whisper in invaluable).  Notably, I have more than once seen an entire *crowd* of such life signs in impossible spaces in small, heavily-populated cells where quest events take place (such as the Ragged Flagon - Cistern).  These life signs have a tendency to appear and vanish as quest events occur.

While we don't yet have [the tools](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Creation_Kit) to properly investigate, I suspect that they are the result of quest scripts "storing" actors (quest-related NPCs) outside of the cell geometry until they are needed.  This is a technique used in other games (including previous TES games) to ensure than an actor is fully loaded before use (to prevent disk lag) or to pre-run scripts prior to interacting with the player.

The resultant life signs are therefore "real" in the sense that there is an actual NPC at that spot, but also "fake", as that the NPC isn't supposed to be visible to the user, due to not yet being "present".

Comment: It's very likely that they are "storing" the actor, as Ben suggested.